# How can I make sub-columns width expand to their parent width?

Tags: html, css

I have my example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfYFq/

Column1 through Column3 divs use up 100% of their parent containers space evenly.  I want the sub columns (sub1, sub2 and sub3) to do the same instead of just being the length of their text.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfYFq/2/

Note second selector.

Comment: your answer made me go learn more specific css selectors.  I'm having ontological shock in retrospect of looking at my jQuery selectors and realizing the obvious :)